# Mybatis spring boot how to create dynamic update query

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis, mybatis-sql

I have given the mybatis update qry below, In which update query specified in a static way. In my case i have to make it dynamic based on the incoming fields.

```
@Update("UPDATE guestpayment SET " +
            "SourceSystemUpdated=#{sourcesysupdated}," +
            "SourceSystemUpdateComment=#{sourcesysupdatedcomments}" +
           "WHERE PrimaryId=#{PrimaryId}")
    void updateguestpayment(Guestpayment updateguestpayment);
```

How to make the update query dynamic based on the incoming fields as jsonobject?

Mapper xml object

```
<!DOCTYPE mapper
    PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
    "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.mybatis.mybatis.dao.GuestpaymentDAO">
<resultMap id="Guestpayment" type="com.mybatis.mybatis.models.Guestpayment" >
    <id property="PrimaryId" column="PrimaryId" javaType="int" jdbcType="integer" />
    <result property="SourceSystemUpdated" column="SourceSystemUpdated" javaType="string" jdbcType="VARCHAR" />
    <result property="SourceSystemUpdateComment" column="SourceSystemUpdateComment" javaType="string" jdbcType="VARCHAR" />
</resultMap>

<update id="updateguestpayment">
    update guestpayment as g
    <set >
        <if test="updateguestpayment.SourceSystemUpdated != null and updateguestpayment.SourceSystemUpdated != ''" >
            g.SourceSystemUpdated = #{updateguestpayment.SourceSystemUpdated} ,
        </if>
        <if test="updateguestpayment.SourceSystemUpdateComment != null and updateguestpayment.SourceSystemUpdateComment != ''">
            <!-- No need to deal with commas, <set> will auto delete extra commas -->
            g.SourceSystemUpdateComment = #{updateguestpayment.SourceSystemUpdateComment},
        </if>
    </set>
    where g.PrimaryId = #{updateguestpayment.PrimaryId}
</update>
</mapper>
```

[image]

Guestpayment.java

```
package com.mybatis.mybatis.models;

import java.util.Date;

public class Guestpayment {
    private int PrimaryId;

    private String sourcesysupdated;
    private String sourcesysupdatedcomments;

    public int getPrimaryId() {
        return PrimaryId;
    }

    public void setPrimaryId(int primaryId) {
        PrimaryId = primaryId;
    }

    public String getSourcesysupdated() {
        return sourcesysupdated;
    }

    public void setSourcesysupdated(String sourcesysupdated) {
        this.sourcesysupdated = sourcesysupdated;
    }

    public String getSourcesysupdatedcomments() {
        return sourcesysupdatedcomments;
    }

    public void setSourcesysupdatedcomments(String sourcesysupdatedcomments) {
        this.sourcesysupdatedcomments = sourcesysupdatedcomments;
    }

}
```

GuestpaymentDAO(interface)

```
@Mapper
@Repository
public interface GuestpaymentDAO {

    void updateguestpayment(@Param("updateguestpayment") Guestpayment updateguestpayment);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Criteria` to create a dynamic update query. In your case, you can do it like below,

```
public class GuestPaymentDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

   public void updateGustPayment(String sourcesysupdated, String sourcesysupdatedcomments, int PrimaryId) {
       CriteriaBuilder cb = this.em.getCriteriaBuilder();

       // create update
       CriteriaUpdate<Guestpayment> update = cb.createCriteriaUpdate(Guestpayment.class);

       // set the root class
       Root e = update.from(Guestpayment.class);

       // set update clause
       if (sourcesysupdated != null) {
           update.set("SourceSystemUpdated", sourcesysupdated);
       }
       if (sourcesysupdatedcomments != null) {
           update.set("SourceSystemUpdateComment", sourcesysupdatedcomments);
       }
       // set where clause
       update.where(cb.equal(e.get("PrimaryId"), PrimaryId));

       // perform update
       this.em.createQuery(update).executeUpdate();
   }
}
```

Comment: Getting null value where should be the table name mentioned?

Comment: Should i have to add table name in my guestpayment object file

Comment: CriteriaUpdate<Guestpayment> update = cb.createCriteriaUpdate(Guestpayment.class); Root e = update.from(Guestpayment.class);

 'Guestpayment' is the table name, if you have a different table name replace it

Answer (score 0):

Why not use mybatis xml and entity to cooperate with each other?
eg :
DAO

```
@Mapper
@Repository
public interface GuestpaymentDAO {

    void updateguestpayment(@Param("updateguestpayment") Guestpayment updateguestpayment);

}
```

mybatis mapper xml file: GuestpaymentDAO.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE mapper
    PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
    "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.example.demo.dao.GuestpaymentDAO">
<resultMap id="Guestpayment" type="com.example.demo.entity.Guestpayment" >
    <id property="PrimaryId" column="PrimaryId" javaType="string" jdbcType="VARCHAR" />
    <result property="SourceSystemUpdated" column="SourceSystemUpdated" javaType="string" jdbcType="VARCHAR" />
    <result property="SourceSystemUpdateComment" column="SourceSystemUpdateComment" javaType="string" jdbcType="VARCHAR" />
</resultMap>

<update id="updateguestpayment">
    update Guestpayment as g
    <set >
        <if test="updateguestpayment.SourceSystemUpdated != null and updateguestpayment.SourceSystemUpdated != ''" >
            g.SourceSystemUpdated = #{updateguestpayment.SourceSystemUpdated} ,
        </if>
        <if test="updateguestpayment.SourceSystemUpdateComment != null and updateguestpayment.SourceSystemUpdateComment != ''">
            <!-- No need to deal with commas, <set> will auto delete extra commas -->
            g.SourceSystemUpdateComment = #{updateguestpayment.SourceSystemUpdateComment},
        </if>
    </set>
    where g.PrimaryId = #{updateguestpayment.PrimaryId}
</update>
</mapper>
```

doc: https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html
src:[src image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yOBc.png)

Comment: Getting error like this "Invalid bound statement (not found): com.mybatis.mybatis.dao.UserMapper.updateguestpayment"

Comment: please check
1. Does the GuestpaymentDAO interface have @Mapper
2. Is the method name of GuestpaymentDAO the same as in GuestpaymentDAO.xml, just updateguestpayment
3. Is the namespace of GuestpaymentDAO.xml the same as the path of GuestpaymentDAO, as described in src image

Comment: Oh, and the path of type in resultMap needs to be the same as Guestpayment

Comment: Sorry, I found a mistake of mine. @Param is required to mark the parameter

Comment: void updateguestpayment(@Param("updateguestpayment") Guestpayment updateguestpayment);

Comment: Still getting the same err"Invalid bound statement (not found): com.mybatis.mybatis.dao.GuestpaymentDAO.updateguestpayment"

Comment: Included code and img of project structure. Kindly check

Comment: Did you specify the scan directory of mybatis in application.yml or applicaiton.properities? Config like this:

mybatis.mapper-locations=classpath:mapper/**/*.xml  #[resource mybatis mapper path]
mybatis.type-aliases-package=com.springh2.demo.dao  #[ dao package path]